# Create areas of interest for a face based on landmarks in R

Tags: r

I am using OpenFace to analyse videos of faces which gives me a CSV with detected landmarks (x and y coordinates) for each frame. Based on these landmarks, I would like to create areas of interest (eyes, forehead including eyebrows, nose and mouth), so that for every pixel in each frame I can assess whether it is within one of these areas of interest.

The detected landmarks look like this:
[image]

Preferably, for each frame I would like to create a matrix of the size of the frame (762 rows and 562 columns) which contains 0 for each pixel that is not belonging to one of the areas of interest and a number for each pixel that falls within such an area of interest, e.g, a 1 for each pixel that is within the area of interest of the eyes.

While it is easy to create the matrix and add a rectangle covering the landmarks, I am struggling to find a somewhat efficient way to add more complex shapes. I would appreciate any ideas on how to achieve this.

**Edit**: There are two steps here that I am struggling with:

1. How to create shapes that capture the area - here, I am currently looking into Delaunay triangulations.
2. How to transform those shapes onto a 2D numerical matrix. With a rectangle, I could just do something like this `matrix[start_y:end_y,start_x:end:x] = 1`, however, how would I achieve this when I have a triangle or an ellipsis?

Here are example landmarks from one frame:

```
structure(list(x_0 = 118.2, x_1 = 119.6, x_2 = 124.6, x_3 = 132.3, 
x_4 = 146.8, x_5 = 171.6, x_6 = 202.9, x_7 = 240.7, x_8 = 283.3, 
x_9 = 324.9, x_10 = 361.3, x_11 = 393.7, x_12 = 417.9, x_13 = 431.5, 
x_14 = 438.4, x_15 = 443, x_16 = 444.7, x_17 = 141.7, x_18 = 164.5, 
x_19 = 191.9, x_20 = 219.5, x_21 = 245.9, x_22 = 312.9, x_23 = 342.8, 
x_24 = 371.2, x_25 = 398, x_26 = 418.2, x_27 = 280.3, x_28 = 280.2, 
x_29 = 280.1, x_30 = 280.3, x_31 = 247.7, x_32 = 263.9, x_33 = 279.8, 
x_34 = 296.1, x_35 = 311.1, x_36 = 172, x_37 = 189.7, x_38 = 213.4, 
x_39 = 231.9, x_40 = 211.7, x_41 = 188.4, x_42 = 325.8, x_43 = 344.9, 
x_44 = 368.3, x_45 = 386.3, x_46 = 369.9, x_47 = 347.2, x_48 = 218.5, 
x_49 = 244, x_50 = 266, x_51 = 279.4, x_52 = 293.7, x_53 = 317.5, 
x_54 = 342.2, x_55 = 318, x_56 = 294.5, x_57 = 279.1, x_58 = 264.7, 
x_59 = 243, x_66 = 279.1, y_0 = 377.4, y_1 = 418.9, y_2 = 460.1, 
y_3 = 500.6, y_4 = 539.4, y_5 = 574.7, y_6 = 604.3, y_7 = 629.4, 
y_8 = 636.2, y_9 = 629.2, y_10 = 606.6, y_11 = 578.6, y_12 = 544.7, 
y_13 = 505.4, y_14 = 464.4, y_15 = 423.6, y_16 = 382.3, y_17 = 344.1, 
y_18 = 330.4, y_19 = 327.4, y_20 = 332.4, y_21 = 342.2, y_22 = 343.8, 
y_23 = 334.9, y_24 = 332.3, y_25 = 336.9, y_26 = 351.7, y_27 = 382.2, 
y_28 = 408.5, y_29 = 434.8, y_30 = 462.1, y_31 = 485.5, y_32 = 490.9, 
y_33 = 495.2, y_34 = 491.4, y_35 = 486.3, y_36 = 383.9, y_37 = 372.1, 
y_38 = 373, y_39 = 388.4, y_40 = 394.6, y_41 = 394.1, y_42 = 390.7, 
y_43 = 375.7, y_44 = 376.4, y_45 = 388.2, y_46 = 397, y_47 = 397.1, 
y_48 = 539, y_49 = 531.3, y_50 = 526.8, y_51 = 530.9, y_52 = 527.4, 
y_53 = 532.5, y_54 = 539.7, y_55 = 556.1, y_56 = 561.8, y_57 = 562.5, 
y_58 = 561.1, y_59 = 554.4, y_66 = 542.8), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: It looks like you would need to do a Delauney tesselation using these points as vertices. Then each triangle needs to be assigned to a region of your choice. Almost any solution in R is going to need you to first pivot this data into long format using `tidyr::pivot_longer(df, everything(), names_sep = '_',  names_to = c('.value', 'point'))`